# Get Jenkins version via java -jar jenkins.war --version without spam output

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface

I'm trying to get the version of the Jenkins war deployed to `/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`. I try running:

```
local version=$(java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version)
```

Unfortunately this prints several silly lines of output to stdout before the version number:

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
1.643
```

Is there a way to tell Jenkins to avoid printing the webroot and "running from" lines? It's annoying and I imagine any attempt to parse it (check the 3rd line of stdout) is prone to breaking in the future.

Comment: FWIW, I've sent a pull request to fix this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/extras-executable-war/pull/4

Comment: This pull request was merged, and as of Jenkins 1.649, it's possible to run `java -jar jenkins.war --version` and get just the version.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since Jenkins 1.649, the `--version` flag causes the version to be printed out directly without any of the extraneous information:

```
$ wget -q http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war/1.649/jenkins.war \
      && java -jar jenkins.war --version
1.649
```

---

*(original answer, pre-Jenkins 1.649)*

As part of the WAR packaging process, the Jenkins version is written to the manifest, which is where the `--version` flag gets its answer from.

So while it may not be particularly pretty, this should be stable:

```
unzip -c /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF \
  | egrep ^Jenkins-Version: | awk '{print $2}'
```

(assuming the availability of `unzip` and friends)

Comment: Soooo helpful. On the Jenkins Docker images, there is no `config.xml` file I can read from (my old standby), so I can call the `war` file directly, like `docker run --rm jenkins/jenkins:slim bash -c "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version"`

Comment: what's this 'friends' all about?

Answer (score 6):

Should this help ( on linux) :

```
head -5  /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml| grep -oP '(?<=<version>).*?(?=</version>)'
```

Comment: This may output a version, but not necessarily the one of the running Jenkins. Instead it only prints the one of the configuration file.

Comment: in some cases you need up to 7 lines of head

Comment: mac grep differs. to just get the whole block: $ grep -in "<version>"  /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/config.xml #=> 4:  <version>2.163</version>

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins version can be easily checked from the **config.xml**  file.

1. Navigate to Jenkins Folder location in the server.
2. Search for **config.xml** file in it. Mostly it will be just directly inside Jenkins folder
3. type command  **head -10 config.xml**
4. It should be in the 7th Line - **<version>2.176.2</version>**

Answer (score 0):

Extract your jankins.war file, it's generally located in your installation directory and navigate to the pom.xml file in META-INF\maven\org.jenkins-ci.main\jenkins-war. In this file, you'll find code similar to the following:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-war</artifactId>
    <version>2.426.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Jenkins war</name>
.....
```

The version is mentioned within the < version > tag. In my case, it's version 2.426.2.